# Accessing objects in opencpu sessions

Tags: r, opencpu

How do I access a specific object in an opencpu "session" in a subsequent function call?

Given a request, say to

```
/ocpu/library/base/R/eval
```

with parameter

```
 expr = "x <- 10; y <- 20"
```

Which gives

```
/ocpu/tmp/x08dfddafe3/R/.val
/ocpu/tmp/x08dfddafe3/R/x
/ocpu/tmp/x08dfddafe3/R/y
/ocpu/tmp/x08dfddafe3/stdout 
/ocpu/tmp/x08dfddafe3/source
/ocpu/tmp/x08dfddafe3/console
/ocpu/tmp/x08dfddafe3/info
```

Now `.val` has the value 20.

Suppose I wanted to pass `x` to

```
ocpu/library/stats/R/rnorm
```

Is there a quick way to that, something like

```
n = x08dfddafe3/R/x
```

in "pseudo"...

Answer (score 3):

Great question. Starting version `1.4.4` there are two ways of doing this:

- You can use `x08dfddafe3::x` to refer to object `x` in the namespace of session `x08dfddafe3`.
- You can pass the full URL http://your.server.com/ocpu/tmp/x08dfddafe3/R/x/rds. If network permits, this will automaticaly grab the object and unserialize it.

Comment: Can I find out the key of the current session from within the call?